# Why isn't my jQuery working?

Tags: jquery

I want to make map1.jpg appear when the user moves his mouse arrow over div called desc1 but I do not see any map coming out when I move my mouse arrow over the div called desc1

```
<div id="desc1" class="descriptions">Desc1</div>
<div id="desc2" class="descriptions">Desc2</div>
<div id="desc3" class="descriptions">Desc3</div>
<div id="themaps1" class="mymaps">
    Head Office Map <img src="map1.jpg">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mymaps').hide();
    $('#desc1').on("hover", function() {    
         $('#themaps1').fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: check your {} there seems to be the wrong order

Comment: You cannot use `hover` with `on()`. `hover` can be bound to two handlers (enter, leave) and `on()` does not support that. Use `hover()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use mouseover instead of hover: http://jsfiddle.net/dehisok/TY5jg/1/

```
$('#desc1').on("mouseover", function() {    
     $('#themaps1').fadeIn();
});
```

**UPD**

To hide it you can also add mouseout-event:

```
 $('#desc1').on("mouseover", function() {    
     $('#themaps1').fadeIn();

 }).on('mouseout', function(){
     $('#themaps1').fadeOut();
 });
```

Comment: what about the `mouseout` event?